# Passing The Bearer Token and the X-Token automatically after successfully authenticated in a protected API with HttpClient C#

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, authorization, dotnet-httpclient

I am using .NET Core API app to consume an external API, After a successfull authentication to the external API, I retrieved the bearer token for the authorization header and then the "X-Token" Header :

```
request.Headers.Add("Authorization","Bearer "+token);
request.Headers.Add("X-Token", token);
```

I want to consume other protected resources in this API, and I need to automatically pass the bearer token in the authorization header and the "X-Token" while calling these resources, I implemented that with storing these two tokens in the Database til I find the right way to pass them automatically, because some tutorials i find them confusing.

***What is the best way to automatically pass these token in the headers of HttpClient requests ?***

***Question Edit*** :

I got an API project that consumes an external protected API resources:

I got 2 methods :

```
    public async Task<Xtoken> Authenticate()
        {
            Xtoken Xtoken= null;
            string bearer = "";
            var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
            string basicToken = Narsa.ClientID + ":" + Narsa.ClientSecret;
            var basicBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(basicToken);
            string basic = Convert.ToBase64String(basicBytes);


            handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
            handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback =
                (httpRequestMessage, cert, cetChain, policyErrors) =>
                {
                    return true;
                };

            #region Get Authorization

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + basic);
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, Narsa.tokenUrl);
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + basic);
            var collection = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
            collection.Add(new("grant_type", "client_credentials"));
            collection.Add(new("scope", "scope"));
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(collection);
            request.Content = content;
            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
      

            BearerToken bearertoken = null;
            string jsonResp = "";
            using (HttpContent httpcontent = response.Content)
            {
                jsonResp = httpcontent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                if (response.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    return null;
                }
              
           
                // Parsing the JSON response to get the token
                try
                {
                    tokenBearer= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BearerToken>(jsonResp);

BearerToken bearertoken = new BearerToken ()
            {
                access_token = tokenBearer.access_token,
                expires_in = tokenBearer.expires_in,
                scope = tokenBearer.scope,
                token_type = tokenBearer.token_type
            };
            _db.BearerToken.Add(bearertoken );
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
         


                }
                catch (Exception e5)
                {
                    e5.InnerException.ToString();
                }
//I want to keep the bearer access token to use it for getting the 2nd token.
                bearer= token.access_token ;

            }

            #endregion


            #region Authenticate 

            Guid GeneratedGUID = Guid.Empty;
            GeneratedGUID = Helpers.generateUUID(GeneratedGUID);
            string narsaGeneratedPassword = "NARSATEST" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + Narsa.narsafinancingSecret;
            narsaGeneratedPassword = Helpers.GenerateNarsaPassword(narsaGeneratedPassword);

           

            HttpClient client1 = new HttpClient(handler);
          //  string basicToken1 = Narsa.ClientID + ":" + Narsa.ClientSecret;
           // var basicBytes1 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(basicToken);
           // string basic1 = Convert.ToBase64String(basicBytes);
          //  string tokenNarsa = "";
//Here I set the bearer token that I got from the first scope above in default authorization header. 
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", bearer);
            HttpRequestMessage request1 = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, Narsa.AuthUri);
            request.Headers.Add("X-Client-ID", Narsa.ClientID);
            request.Headers.Add("X-Request-ID", GeneratedGUID.ToString());
            request.Headers.Add("X-Request-Application-Name", "ADD");

            var postData = new
            {
                UserName = Narsa.user,
                Password = narsaGeneratedPassword
            };

            var content1 = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(postData), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            request1.Content = content1;
            var response1 = await client.SendAsync(request1);

            string jsonResp1 = "";
            using (HttpContent httpcontent1 = response1.Content)
            {
                jsonResp1 = httpcontent1.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
              
                try
                {
                    Xtoken= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<XToken>(jsonResp);
                }
                catch (Exception e5)
                {
                    e5.InnerException.ToString();
                }

            }
            JetonNarsa jeton = new JetonNarsa()
            {
                access_token = tokenBearer.access_token,
                expires_in = tokenBearer.expires_in,
                scope = tokenBearer.scope,
                token_type = tokenBearer.token_type
            };
            _db.JetonNarsa.Add(jeton);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
         

            return Xtoken;
            #endregion

  

        }
```

as you may notice I stored these two access-tokens in my DB as a TEST in order to call them in the other methods while performing a HttpClient Request . ***E.g***

```
  public async Task<ResponseOptions> DeclareAPledge(DeclarNantissement_DTO obj)
        {
            Guid GeneratedGUID = Guid.Empty;
            GeneratedGUID = Helpers.generateUUID(GeneratedGUID);
            //I get these acess token them from my DB in order to call a protected action in that external API 
            var token = _db.JetonNarsa.Select(x => x.access_token).FirstOrDefault();
            var bearer = _db.BearerToken.Select(x => x.access_token).FirstOrDefault();
            
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, Narsa.DeclarationNantiUri);
             client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", bearer);

            request.Headers.Add("X-Client-ID", Narsa.ClientID);
            request.Headers.Add("X-Request-ID", GeneratedGUID.ToString());
            request.Headers.Add("X-Request-Application-Name", "ADD");
            request.Headers.Add("X-Token", token);

            DeclarNantissement_DTO postData = new DeclarNantissement_DTO
            {
                idRequete = GeneratedGUID,
                codeSF = obj.codeSF,
                immatVeh1 = obj.immatVeh1,
                immatVeh2 = obj.immatVeh2,
                immatVeh3 = obj.immatVeh3,
                numChassis = obj.numChassis,
                dateNantissement = obj.dateNantissement,
                TypeVehicule = obj.TypeVehicule,
                numContrat = obj.numContrat,
                numWW = obj.numWW,
                idBeneficiare=obj.idBeneficiare,
                idType=obj.idType,
                intituleBeneficiaire=obj.intituleBeneficiaire,
                villeRC =obj.villeRC

            };
            var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(postData), null, "application/json");
            request.Content = content;
            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        

            string jsonResp = "";
            ResponseOptions Resp = null;
            using (HttpContent httpcontent = response.Content)
            {
                jsonResp = httpcontent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonResp))
                {

                    return null;
                }

                try
                {
                    Resp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseOptions>(jsonResp);
                  
                }
                catch (Exception Ex)
                {
                }

            }
            return Resp;


        }
```

****How to store these tokens in order to use them for protected actions of the external API ?***

Comment: You made the question very vague with your edit. This is not a discussion forum, nor can we make an optimal implementation for you. Your question needs more _focus_. And "What is the best way" will only attract options answers, as that is usually subjective. So you should give us your code [mcve] and explain where you get stuck. Also please read [ask].

Comment: @JHBonarius I re-edited my question, can you see it please ?

Comment: I still don't fully understand your question. You are already storing the Tokes in de DB. Apart from that, you are not showing how you are sending requests to the external api. Because you could just add the token to the httpclient used to query that api. Also, in your code you're just swallowing exceptions. That's almost never a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You put them in the default request headers of `HttpClient`. E.g.

```cs
var client = new HttpClient
{
    DefaultRequestHeaders = 
    {
        Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken)
    },
};
```

You can also add custom headers like

```cs
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("myHeader", "MyValue");
```

Note: these will thus be used by ALL things using this `HttpClient` instance.

Comment: Hi @JHBonarius, so you mean I populate that HttpClient App, with the retrieved token once I authenticate my app to the External API ? thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can set `DefaultRequestHeaders` for an existing httpclient and those values wil be used for every request. Or, at least, that is how one could do it. You're not sharing a lot of specifics about your app.

Comment: I just edited the question, in order to be more specific and clear, thanks for your help.